# Array of template type in PL/pgSQL function using %TYPE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql, array, functions

I have a PostgreSQL database and a PL/pgSQL function that currently has arguments with copied types (for example `IN arg_1 table_1.column_1%TYPE`).

I want to update it so one of those arguments is actually an array of elements with that copied type. If it were a "normal" type, I'd just add `[]` after the type, like `IN arg_1 integer[]`. Following that logic, I tried adding the square brackets right after `%TYPE`, but I get a syntax error.

I couldn't find anything about in the Postgres docs, nor did my google fu yield useful answers.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The [`%TYPE` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE) can only copy the exact type. But there is a simple workaround to register the according array type: Create a (temporary) table or view with the desired array type.

Template table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (i int);
```

(Temporary) view to register the array type, optionally empty (`LIMIT 0`):

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW v_foo_i_arr AS
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT i FROM foo LIMIT 0) AS i_arr;
```

***Or*** a (temporary) table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo_i_arr AS
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT i FROM foo LIMIT 0) AS i_arr;
```

Now your function works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_arr_test(v_foo_i_arr.i_arr%TYPE)
  RETURNS foo.i%TYPE AS  -- example: return element type
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN $1[2];
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You might as well make that a ***temporary*** view or table, since the type in the function signature is **converted to the underlying type immediately**. No persisted connection to the used template. So it's no problem that temp objects are dropped at the end of the session.

#### Polymorphic type

You ***might*** be better off with a [polymorphic type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) to begin with. This works for *any* array type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_arr_test_polymorphic(ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS ANYELEMENT AS  -- derived from input type
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN $1[2];
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96754/1)

Note that using a `%TYPE` declaration *inside* the function body actually works dynamically in that it looks up the type in the system catalog at the first call of every session.

Related question on SO:

- [PL/pgSQL - %TYPE and ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17659995/939860)